Cannot access ASP.NET Core MVC app when run with docker
I have a simple ASP.NET Core MVC project. When I containerized this project, in container logs it shows

Now listening on: http://[::]:8080

But when I tried to access this on web browser, I get this error

This page isn't working

I tried by using this url http://<container_ip>:8080 in place of <container_ip>. I used the actual IP of my running container, but I only see this message:

This page can't be reached


Did you publish the port when you started the container?

No, i didn't.
Can you please guide me about this.

What command did you use to start the container?

docker run -p 8080:80 my_project

You can see in the logs that the application is listening on port 8080 (that's the default for .NET 8 containerized applications using the aspnet image as the base image). So that's the port that you need to map to a host port.
Your current command
docker run -p 8080:80 my_project 

maps port 80. To map port 8080 instead, you should use
docker run -p 8080:8080 my_project 

Then you should be able to access the application on http://localhost:8080/.
